# Asterisk record number of extensions

Tags: asterisk, phone-call, recording

I have Asterisk, running fine for few years already. I already have Monitor/MixMonitor recording certain queues.

Now, I would like to record 5-6 extensions, which are not part of a queue.
What would be the best way to do this, i.e. to record them as part of a group?

Answer (score 1):

That depend of your current dialplan.

For outbound you can set some variable like "record=yes,record_group=somegroup".

For inbound you need check database or astdb.

Check how it done in freepbx.org web for example.